# How do I adjust a dropdown menu to appear over the content?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a jQuery dropmenu for the navigation this site: `http://184.173.208.195/~secoast/` which is obviously in development. The drop menu works correctly despite a jQuery error that says .dropmenu is not a function.

The current main issue is that menu is hiding behind the other content on the page. I suspect this may be due in part to the jQuery error. The dropmenu module originally had a noconflict part included so that it would not conflict with other library modules.

To cover all bases, here is the beginning of the jQuery file (jquery.dropmenu.js):

```
$.fn.dropmenu = function(custom) {

    // Default plugin settings
    var defaults = {
      openAnimation: "size",
        closeAnimation: "slide",
        openClick: false,
        openSpeed: 300,
        closeSpeed: 200,
        closeDelay: 200,
        onHide: function(){},
        onHidden: function(){},
        onShow: function(){},
        onShown: function(){},
        zindex: 100,
        openMenuClass: 'open',
        autoAddArrowElements: true
    };
```

Then on the main file I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-one").dropmenu({
            openAnimation: "size",
            closeAnimation: "slide",
            openSpeed: 300,
            closeSpeed: 200,
            closeDelay: 500,
            zindex: 1000
    });
});
</script>
```

Lastly here is the navigation menu:

```
<ul id="nav-one" class="dropmenu css-only">
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Your work</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a href="#">Why the Southeast</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Your work</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a href="#">What We Do</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Office</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Custom projects</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a href="#">Resources</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help in getting this sorted out will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you decide to remove the no conflict code ? Was this working at some point ? Are you using other libraries ?

Comment: do you have any overflow hidden applied to anything?

Comment: jquery.dropmenu.js is empty.

Comment: `z-index` is what you need to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying anything else i sugest you change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dropmenu.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dropmenu.js"></script>
```

notice the `../` that was removed, no doubt a minor miss, but quite important ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try extending the `.dropdown` class with `position: relative;` and `z-index: 100;` as;

```
.dropmenu {
  float: left;
  margin: 50px 0 0 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Also noticed the error; "*Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropmenu'*".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `z-index` to make the element above everything, by using a very high number.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see I simply changed the style with `z-index: 9005`

Comment: if you need to see the image bigger here is the [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofsc5.png)